# Delaying with timezones and utcOffset?

Tags: time, norway

Im working with an application dealing with timezones and I hope someone here might be able to answer this timezone-related question.

Let us say that I am currently located in Norway.

The UTC-time is now: 07:00 I got the UTC-time from here: http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx.

And my time in Norway is 09:00.

So, UTC-time is 2 hours behind "Norway"-time.

I would expect that another way to express this difference would be that Norways timezone is +2 from UTC.

But it seems that im missunderstanding something here. Having a look here (world-map with timezones): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

We can see that Norway is +1.

So now lets make an example demonstrating my problem.

Im in Canada now which is UTC -6. I need to get some real-time data from Norway and I need it to display in Norweigan time.

I would start by get the UTC-time which is currently: 07:13

Next step would be to "convert" UTC (07:13) to Norweigan time by adding the correct time based on Norways timezone.

This is where I get confused..I know that Norways is 2 hours ahead...But looking at the timezone map I get the impression that its only 1 hour.

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Norway uses [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)—does this account for the additional hour from UTC (which does not have such a concept)? Also, if you're doing this programmatically, do not attempt to roll-your-own solution, use something like [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you. So its the daylight saving time that makes the actual difference between norway and UTC 2 hours instead of one hour. Im programming in javascript so I will use momentJs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Norway uses [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), and this probably accounts for the additional hour's difference from UTC (which does not have such a concept).

Note that if you're doing working with time zones and localising times programmatically, do not attempt to roll-your-own solution, use an established and robust solution like [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) (Python) or the brilliant [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).